# Uso do filter no ng-repeat em jade templates

Tags: node.js, angularjs-directives, express.js, jade

Pessoal acho que estou fazendo algo errado mas não estou conseguindo encontrar o erro no código.

```
ul(class='list-group')
        li(class="list-group-item", ng-repeat="v in votadas | filter: '-votos'")
          h4 Música: {{ v.titulo }} | Votos: {{ v.votos }}
```

Minha intenção é que as músicas sejam ordenadas pela ordem das mais votadas. Quando excluo o filter do ng-repeat funciona mas com o filter nada acontece.

Alguma luz?

Answer (score 0):

Bem, pesquisei bastante e não encontrei a solução via filter. Então recorri ao array.sort do javascript e funcionou direitinho.